# Delimitar y poner en separado datos en cada TxtBox

Tags: c#

¿Cómo están compañeros del foro?

Se trata de que uso un terminal llamado [Termite gratuito](https://www.compuphase.com/software_termite.htm) que lee el puerto serie, envío una letra B mayúscula y seguido envía también el \r.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La configuración es esta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como dije arriba, con Termite he enviado el comando B. Su respuesta es esta:

**#I225.7O226.2L006B100V25.7F50.2H50.2R0080S€„€ˆ„À**

A partir de la página 4 indica el comando a enviar que es el B y luego explica todo lo que recibe después.

[Ver documento PDF.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u9e22w8iwnw240v/Protocolo%20Comandos%20Salicru%20SAI%20UPS.pdf?dl=0)

En el programa Termite al enviar el comando B, recibe toda una trama de Bytes en el cual quiero ponerlo por separado en Windows Form 4.7.2 .net o superior con Visual Studio Community 2022 gratuito.

En la versión que tengo, no se usa la C, T ni la Q. De todas formas al recibir las tramas de Bytes lo vas a ver.

Leer la S de forma independiente lo veo complicado, lo dejaré más adelante hasta cuando consiga lo más sencillos.

Quiero saber la forma más directa que al recibir la trama de Bytes, al menos me centro en vez de esto con la S:
**#I226.6O226.6L006B100V25.7F50.2H50.2R0120S€„€ˆ„À**

Me centro sin la S con esto indicado abajo:
**#I226.6O226.6L006B100V25.7F50.2H50.2R0120**

Me imagino que todo esto se almacenará en una variable tipo string, luego habrá que separarlo por cada textBox que se muestre.

Ejemplo con Windows Form.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Algún ejemplo de cómo separar la trama de Bytes y mostrarlo de forma independiente en el Windows Form en código C#?

Muchas gracias por leer hasta aquí.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una aclaración, lo que tu tienes no es una trama de bytes es solo un string. Es habitual que al comunicarse con dispositivos la respuesta llegue en una trama de bytes, pero no es tu caso.

Para separar una string puedes usar la función `split(separador)` que divide aquel en string en partes que están separadas por el `separador`, retornando un `array` con cada parte.

Además esta función acepta como argumento un array de separadores, lo que viene genial para tu caso.

Ejemplo:

```
string entrada = "#I225.7O226.2L006B100V25.7F50.2H50.2R0080S€„€ˆ„À\r\n\r\n";

char[] separadores = { '#', 'I', 'O', 'L', 'B', 'V', 'F', 'H', 'R', 'S' };

var salida = entrada.Split(separadores,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

foreach (var c in salida)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c);
}
```

Si te fijas el array de separadores está compuesto por las letras que indican el "protocolo" de respuesta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muy bueno tu ejemplo. Hay un problema, que es en modo consola y funciona de maravilla. En este caso uso Windows Form y cada letra con su valor corresponde a su textBox para mostrar sus datos.
Ver captura: https://i.postimg.cc/zfzvQ10w/SAI.jpg
Muchas gracias mi muy distinguido amigo.

Comment: @Meta Es solo un ejemplo y es que es irrelevante si es de consola o windows forms, tu tienes que hacer algo como `textbox1.Text = salida[0]; textbox2.Text = salida[1];  //etc` nada más. Recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada si ha resuelto el problema. Saludos

Comment: Como aclaración para tus futuras preguntas. En este caso he respondido a modo genérico y es porque tu no has puesto código alguno, particularmente no tengo problema en responder en especifico para windows forms, pero ahí tienes que haber puesto tu código, partiendo que no se como le has llamado a tus `textboxt`, ni tampoco como vas a ingresar el string de entrada, y que para probar la respuesta tengo que suponer todo eso y además crear un proyecto con todos esos items

Comment: Me ha servido las respuestas. Muchísima gracias mi muy distinguido amigo. Ya lo he puesto en verde.

Comment: @Meta Un gustazo, suerte en tu proyecto

Comment: Me va funcionando el proyecto, pero solo en una trama. Muchas gracias. Ver imagen aquí: https://i.postimg.cc/63BSKkgc/SAI-Csharp-copia.jpg